# How do I learn to craft Engineering's Cardboard Assassin in Shadowlands?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The Engineering item **Cardboard Assassin** has caught on as being useful in Shadowlands dungeons, however it's an engineering item from an older expansion "Cataclysm" that I'm not familiar with.

The typical way that one learns to craft new items is by leveling the profession, in this case Engineering, and the new recipes become available from the profession trainer.

In this case, Cardboard Assassin doesn't seem to be able to be learned from the vendor in the typical fashion.

I know with some professions I have to get a recipe to learn how to craft certain items. Is that the case with Cardboard Assassin?

This is also the first time I've been an Engineer, so perhaps there's something unique about Engineering compared to something like Tailoring?

How do I learn the recipe for Cardboard Assassin?

Comment: -1 for not doing the research. it's right there on the 3rd highest rated comment.

Comment: I did the research, and submitted an answer to the question. Is the answer visible to you?

My goal is to get the Q&A out of Wowhead comments and have access to it directly here rather than buried in comments. Here we can edit the answer together as a community and leave a useful artifact for people in the future trying to find the best answer. Wowhead comments are inferior to the StackExchange format.

Comment: @ReedDunkle If your goal for this Q&A is to keep it up to date and let people edit the answer along with WoW updates, you should tag your answer as a "Community answer", which will be more inviting for other users to edit it

Comment: @ReedDunkle You could use [this Q&A](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357691/how-does-lost-loot-work) as a reference for community-managed Q&A

Comment: @Zoma I appreciate the suggestion. I'll look into "Community answer". At first glance, I'm not sure how it is different from any other StackExchange Q&A where people can make edits/suggestions?

Comment: @Zoma I see that the edits are different now. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) explains what community posts are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is learned randomly through crafting, rather than learned at the trainer.<sup>[[1]](https://www.wowhead.com/spell=84425/cardboard-assassin#comments:id=1224244)</sup>

The prerequisite seems to be that you've learned **Cataclysm Engineering**.<sup>[[2]](https://www.wowhead.com/spell=84425/cardboard-assassin#comments:id=3304271)</sup> It's not clear if the items crafted need to be from Cataclysm Engineering to learn Cardboard Assassin.

I followed these steps and learned the recipe for Cardboard Assassin:

1. In Stormwind/Orgrimmar, go to the Engineering trainer and learn
   **Cataclysm Engineering**
2. Craft several **Electrified Ether** (materials are 2x **Volatile Air**). I learned Cardboard Assassin after crafting 10-30 of these. It's random, but the chances of learning it seem pretty high.

A **Tinker's Kit** is required to apply the effect to the belt. Tinker's Kits are sold from the Engineering vendor in Stormwind/Orgrimmar.

---

Sources:

- [1] https://www.wowhead.com/spell=84425/cardboard-assassin#comments:id=1224244
- [2] https://www.wowhead.com/spell=84425/cardboard-assassin#comments:id=3304271